# SQL query ( Do I use COUNT?)

Tags: sql, oracle

Tables are:

```
ARTIST(artistID,LastName,FirstName,Nationality,DOB)

CUSTOMER(customerID,FirstName,LastName)

CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT(artistID,CustomerID)
```

Need help with making a SQL query for this question:

List the name of any customers who have an interest in all the artists from the United States.

Very new to SQL would appreciate someone pushing me in the right direction.

this is what I have so far, no idea if I'm on the right track.

```
SELECT C.FirstName, C.LastName, A.NATIONALITY
FROM dtoohey.CUSTOMER C, dtoohey.ARTIST A, dtoohey.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT I
WHERE C.CUSTOMERID=I.CUSTOMERID AND A.ARTISTID=I.ARTISTID;
```

Edit: using oracle SQL developer

Comment: You may also want to use a distinct because this looks like Customer is going to repeat for every artist.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL? Don't use inappropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

You want to join all three tables together and then specify 'United States' as nationality in the `WHERE` clause, I believe...

```
SELECT C.*
FROM Customer C
INNER JOIN customer_artist_int ca ON c.customerID = ca.customerID
INNER JOIN artist a ON a.artistID = ca.artistID
WHERE a.Nationality = 'United States'
```

**EDIT:** I'm noticing now that you said you want to list customers who are interested in **all** of the artists from the United States. Do you mean you only want customers who are interested in *every single* United States artist? As in, if John Smith is only interested in *one* United States artist, his name should *not* be included? That logic would be a bit more in-depth but I'll wait for your instruction to continue.

Comment: that's correct, only customers who are interested in all of the artists from US should be included

Answer (score 0):

If you join the customers with the artists from United States and group by the customers, you can then use the `having` clause to compare the count with the total count of artists from the United States.  Customer rows are returned if the count matches:

```
select c.FirstName, c.LastName
  from customer c
  join customer_artist_int cai
    on cai.CustomerID = c.customerID
  join artist a
    on a.artistID = cai.artistID
   and a.Nationality = 'United States'
 group by c.customerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                     from artist
                    where Nationality = 'United States')
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming nationality is a string and artists are unique:

```
WITH us_artists_cnt AS (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS us_artists_cnt 
  FROM Artists
  WHERE Nationality = 'United States'),
customers_artists AS (
    SELECT C.customerID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, A.NATIONALITY, count(*) cnt
    FROM Customer C
    INNER JOIN customer_artist_int CA on CA.customerID = C.customerID
    INNER JOIN Artist A on A.artistID = CA.artistID
    WHERE A.nationality = 'United States'
    GROUP BY C.customerID)
SELECT C.customerID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, A.NATIONALITY, cnt
FROM customers_artists
WHERE cnt = us_artists_cnt
```

This is close.  Let me know how this goes for you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your first `WITH` is counting all United States artists. Let's say it gets back 5. Your second `WITH` is joining the three tables and counting the records as `cnt`. If I'm a user and I like 5 European bands, would the second `WITH` not return `cnt` as 5, thus making `cnt = us_artists_cnt` true? I believe you'd need to include `WHERE A.nationality = 'United States'` in the second `WITH` as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! This is exactly what i need!, I've run parts if of this query separately and it returns the values I'm looking for. however when I run the whole query I'm getting the error "missing select keyword" Line" 5 column: 1. it's so close! just need to work out this error

Comment: @joel0z I am a TSQL guy so I'm not too familiar with `WITH`, however I believe you should try replacing the second `WITH` with a `,` instead. Something like `WITH us_artists_cnt AS (...), customers_artists AS (...) SELECT ...`

Comment: Yes @TylerRoper you are correct.  I've removed the second WITH and replaced it with a comma. How does it work now OP?